# Is there any way to mitigate the cost of multiprocessing.Process.start()?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

So I've been tooling around with threads and processes in Python, and along the way I cooked up a pattern that allows the same class to be pitched back and forth between threads and/or processes without losing state data by using by-name RPC calls and Pipes.

Everything works fine, but it takes an absurd amount of time to start a process as compared to loading the state from a pickled file, and Thread.start() returns immediately, so there's only the minor cost of the constructor.  So: what's the best way start a Process with a large initial state without an absurd startup time.  Snips and debug output below, the size of "counter" is just over 34,000K pickled to file with mode 2.

```
...
elif command == "load":
    # RPC call - Loads state from file "pickle_name":
    timestart = time.time()
    print do_remote("take_pickled_state", pickle_name)
    print "Load cost: " + str(time.time() - timestart)
elif command == "asproc":
    if type(_async) is multiprocessing.Process:
        print "Already running as a Process you fool!."
    else:
        do_remote("stop")
        _async.join()
        p_pipe.close()
        p_pipe, c_pipe = multiprocessing.Pipe()
        timestart = time.time()
        _async = multiprocessing.Process(target = counter, args = (c_pipe,))
        # Why is this so expensive!!?!?!?! AAARRG!!?!
        _async.start()
        print "Start cost: " + str(time.time() - timestart)
elif command == "asthread":
    if type(_async) is threading.Thread:
        print "Already running as a Thread you fool!."
    else:

        # Returns the state of counter on stop:
        timestart = time.time()
        counter = do_remote("stop")
        print "Proc stop time: " + str(time.time() - timestart)
        _async.join()
        p_pipe.close()
        p_pipe, c_pipe = multiprocessing.Pipe()
        timestart = time.time()
        _async = threading.Thread(target = counter, args = (c_pipe,))
        _async.start()
        print "Start cost: " + str(time.time() - timestart)
...
```

Corresponding debug statements:

```
Waiting for command...
  >>> load
Load complete.
Load cost: 2.18700003624
Waiting for command...
  >>> asproc
Start cost: 23.3910000324
Waiting for command...
  >>> asthread
Proc stop time: 0.921999931335
Start cost: 0.0629999637604
```

Edit 1:
OS: Win XP 64.
Python version: 2.7.x
Processor: Xeon quad core.

Edit 2:
The thing I really don't get is it takes ~1 sec for the process stop to return the entire state, but it takes 20x longer to receive the state and start. (debug outputs added)

Comment: First, is this on Windows or POSIX?

Comment: Second: You probably don't want to pass 34K of initial data directly between processes if you're trying to start up in milliseconds. While shared memory, mmap'd files, etc. are mainly thought of as ways to share mutable state, they can also be used—and without any of the headaches—for passing immutable starting state.

Comment: A possible optimisation would be starting the worker processes before you need them, and reusing them.

Comment: 34M actually (^-^).  And I know that's kind of a nonsense initial size, but that was the point of the test - to see just how bad it could get.  (I've let this particular worker get to 3gb once)  Anyway, the Piped/RPC design is such that the whole thing will work over a network - and unless I'm mistaken, shared memory is not going to work for me in that case.

@millimoose : The design supports that via the load command (as well as pause/reinit/etc. not shown)  Again I'm tooling around the edges, basically trying to simulate offloading a task to a remote system.